# Do I need to disable debugImplementation and releaseImplementation before creating APK for release

Tags: java, android, gradle

I use a library named LeakCanary which allows me to find anything that cause memory leaks. I add the following references in gradle:

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.2'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.2'
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-support-fragment:1.6.2'
```

To use the library. Now, before creating an APK full release for the store, do I need to comment the above lines, or is it safe to just keep them and comment only the line to use the library in the main activity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

release builds would only contain `leakcanary-android-no-op` ... where `no op` means "no operation"; therefore one can assume no side-effects there; except adding the size of that dummy package to the release build's package size. that `no op` dummy package is only required, because else any occurrence of `LeakCanary` in the code would be unknown.

Comment: So, with me leaving those on, the APK size would increase?

Comment: you must leave the `no-op` package there, else your code will break. that's the reason why that package even exists. obviously, the release build would in general be slightly smaller than the debug build. and it might be a few kilobytes only, nothing too dramatic. alternatively, you'd have to remove it altogether... including all occurrences of class `LeakCanary` in code, which removing the `releaseImplementation` would break.

Comment: If you really hate unused dependencies in a build file you can remove it, actually, there is not much code needed for LeakCanary, just an init line `LeakCanary.install(this)` with a `refWatcher`. So it's up to you. I would recommend keeping `releaseImplementation`, there would be less hustle while developing new versions.